# The red box that refers to other dataframes will only show part of the box (only show over land but not water, see image)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, maps, data-frame

[image: the red box refers to other dataframes but it's only showing over land and not over the ocea, ie, the box is an incomplete square]

the red box refers to other dataframes but it's only showing over land and not over the ocea, ie, the box is an incomplete square

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have used a Clip option on the Data Frame tab of your Data Frame properties for the data frame that you are using as your overview.

The ArcGIS Online Help describes **[Clipping the Data Frame](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000000q000000)**.

Change its current setting to No Clipping and I think you will see your Extent Indicator in its entirety.